# ReactJs component structure - Form inside modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am using the react-bootstrap Modal, Form and Button.

Desiring the functionality of clicking the button should open the modal with a form inside it. After filling out the form, one clicks a button (on the **modal**) and it validates the form data and posts it through a REST API.

I got far enough to figure out that my component split should be as follows:

A button component, a modal component and a form component.

What would be the correct way to structure these components in terms of props/state and placing the functions for validating the data? I am having trouble in understanding the child/parent relationship and when it's applicable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Components:**

1. **App Component:** This is going to be the top level component
2. **Button Component** (If its just a button can also be
   just a button): 
   If this is just a button you can keep this has a just a button in `App component`, if you are willing to reuse this with some custom element place it in a component.
3. **Modal component:** This is going to hold your modal like **header**,**body**,**footer**
4. **Form component:** This is a component which will hold the form and its validations.

**Component Tree:**

App Component will contain a **state** like **showModal**, we need to have a handler to set this value and this handler gets triggered when the button is clicked.

```
import FormModal from './FormModal';   

class App extends React.Component {
   state = {
    showModal : false
  }

  showModalHandler = (event) =>{
    this.setState({showModal:true});
  }

  hideModalHandler = (event) =>{
    this.setState({showModal:false});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="shopping-list">
        <button type="button" onClick={this.showModalHandler}>Click Me! 
        </button>
      </div>
      <FormModal showModal={this.sate.showModal} hideModalHandler={this.hideModalHandler}></FormModal>
    );
  }
}
```

**Form Modal:**

```
import FormContent from './FormContent';

class FormModal extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const formContent = <FormContent></FormContent>;
    const modal = this.props.showModal ? <div>{formContent}</div> : null;
    return (
      <div>
        {modal}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default FormModal;
```

Hope that helped!

Comment: This helped a great deal - Thanks!! How come we are passing the hideModalHandler as props to FormContent though? Wouldn't the form not care whether the modal is visible or not?

Comment: yes, that correct, we have make use of hideModalHandler in FormModal

Comment: Make sense - The form is supposed to be submitted through a click on the modal form - How am I supposed to pass a function of the form (handleSubmit) to the onClick event of the modal?

Answer (score 3):

For basic pseudo code

**Main Component:**

```
import Modal from './Modal'
class Super extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        this.state={
            modalShowToggle: false
        }
    }
    ModalPopUpHandler=()=>{
        this.setState({
            modalShowToggle: !modalShowToggle
        })
    }
    render(){
        return(){
            <div>
                <Button title='ModalOpen' onClick='this.ModalPopUpHandler'> </Button>
                <ModalComponent show={this.state.modalShowToggle}>
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

---

**ModalPopUp component:**

```
import FormComponent from 'FormComponent'
class ModalComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            modalToggle: props.show
        }
    }
    render(){
        if(this.state.modalToggle){
            return(
                <div> 
                    <div className='ModalContainer'>
                        <FormComponent />
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Form Component:**

```
import Button from './Button'
class FormComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        this.state={
            submitButtonToggle: true,
            username: ''
        }
    }

    inputHandler=(e)=>{
        if(e){
            this.setState({
                username: e.target.value
            })
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <input type='text' value='this.state.username' id='username' onChange='inputHandler' />
                <Button title='Submit' disabled={this.state.username.length > 0}> </Button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Above are the basic *superComponent* which we have rendered in app/main entry file.
And *form || Modal Component.* are the child component.

So in modal component I have called the same Form-component.

Here in *Form-component* input type handler, submit button is disabled from state.. with input string length we are handling its validation.

I hope it works for you.